# how to refresh detail view for iphone

Tags: iphone

If i do this in detail view

```
labelb.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

labelb.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

then when i go back to main page and click on any row then details section are overlapping with previous details how to always clear cells  when going back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `-viewWillDisappear` method to reset the default values:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear {
  //reset stuff here...
}
```

Comment: do i need to add some tag value?? to label